# nginx not starting at reboot after gitlab installation

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx (1.6) in ubuntu server (14.04).

After that, I installed gitlab. I didn't realize it came with its own nginx. I uninstalled gitlab later.

After installing gitlab, my first nginx began to never start at boot as a service. This means:

- If I hit `sudo netstat -anp` I don't see the corresponding entry in 0.0.0.0:80.
- If I hit `sudo nginx -s reload` and then `sudo netstat -anp` I see the corresponding entry I mentioned.

I thought I could fixing it by doing:

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx remove
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

After removing gitlab, but it did not help me (i.e. after reboot, nginx does not automatically start).

I revised the `/etc/init.d/nginx` just to see that `$DAEMON` is still `/usr/sbin/nginx`.

**Question**: What should I check to see the problem here (or: what could the problem be)? `sudo nginx -s reload` works with no problems at all.

Comment: Tumbleweed here!